# How to let user highlight TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm working on an Android project with some TextViews for students but I'll want users to long-click and get option to highlight some parts of the contents with different colors like it happens in some Bible apps or Adobe Reader. The option to mark text color happens on long click.
I'll appreciate any guide to make this work.

Comment: Do you want this? https://android--code.blogspot.in/2016/03/android-highlight-text-in-textview.html

Comment: your question is unclear, refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've updated the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use Spannable string to style the test 
Example :

```
String firstWord = "Hello";
String secondWord = "World!";

TextView tvHelloWorld = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHelloWorld);

// Create a span that will make the text red
ForegroundColorSpan redForegroundColorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(
        getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));

// Use a SpannableStringBuilder so that both the text and the spans are mutable
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(firstWord);

// Apply the color span
ssb.setSpan(
        redForegroundColorSpan,            // the span to add
        0,                                 // the start of the span (inclusive)
        ssb.length(),                      // the end of the span (exclusive)
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); // behavior when text is later inserted into the SpannableStringBuilder
                                           // SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE means to not extend the span when additional
                                           // text is added in later

// Add a blank space
ssb.append(" ");

// Create a span that will strikethrough the text
StrikethroughSpan strikethroughSpan = new StrikethroughSpan();

// Add the secondWord and apply the strikethrough span to only the second word
ssb.append(secondWord);
ssb.setSpan(
        strikethroughSpan,
        ssb.length() - secondWord.length(),
        ssb.length(),
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Set the TextView text and denote that it is Editable
// since it's a SpannableStringBuilder
tvHelloWorld.setText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

[image]

Source : https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-TextView

Comment: Sorry this isn't what I wanted. I've updated the question to reflect what I really need. I want users to long click on text view to get option to highlight some parts of the texts

Comment: according to update of your post: your need to set clickablespan in every word , when a work is click then you change the font size or color or start animation the work which is selected . clickablespan and SpannableString only support click it not supported longclick